# Xcode Storyboard: show custom view instead default view in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to iOS development. In the Storyboard, I have put the Tab View Controller from the object library

In one tab, I have put a table view controller and in the other tab I have a custom view.

Now in my

```
UiTableViewController viewDidLoad()
```

I want to check a variable: if this variable is false I to want show another view instead the table view.
This new view must not be a modal view because I want this view inside the tab bar and not over.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not using storyboard is probably a safer option. Although you can use storyboard and then in viewDidLoad set your `[self.tableView setHidden:YES]` and unhide the other depending on your if statement. This is a work-around. Probably better options out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a TableViewController, you can use only the Tableview. 
You can do what you want by replacing the TableViewController by a ViewController.

After, two ways :

**First way - Storyboard**

- You add the TableView in it
- You define your viewController as the Delegate/Datasource of your new tableview
  The result will be the same as in the TableViewcontroller but you'll be able to handle the TableView as you want.

**Second way - Programmation :**

You declare and use the TableView only by programming. This is nearly the same thing than the first way, but you don't use the StoryBoard.

I already used this way to allow the user to choose between a TableView and a CollectionView.

**After**

Then, you can check your variable, and if you want to display something else than the TableView, you only have to use self.tableView.hidden = YES to hide it and display what you want.

I prefer the second way because you handle everything, but it's a little (very little ^^) bit harder. 
;)

Answer (score 0):

if you wish your controler to handle views dynamicly, i would recomend not to use UITableViewController. Instead use a UIViewController, and than inside that view controllers view (self.view) you can add and manage the visibility of any kind of views (in your case UITableView & some custom view).

Also, there, you can manage the table view delegate methods same as in UItableViewController.

Good luck in your design :)